# How add Widget as Matrix by LatLng coordinate between location and point in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I add widget by location coordinates?
I have my currents location and a house location and I want to show it when camera its open on the screen and calculate where put it on screen , I know can do it with AR but I want to do it without AR

sorry for my English

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the user's current location (coordinates), you should be able to calculate a compass bearing from one coordinate to the other, using formalae like the ones on this page:
https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/

Knowing how far and which direction the user should walk, you can figure out what the angle is between this heading and the user's current heading, using a compass package like this one:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_compass

Now the only thing left to do is to visualize them on the camera. In your case, I'd use a `Stack` widget, and overlay a rotated (according to the angle you got from the compass app) arrow on top of the camera view, which you can get from a package like `camera` https://pub.dev/packages/camera.